# Не могу получить данные через FormData

Tags: jquery, ajax, отправка, formdata

Нужна Ваша помощь. У меня проблема с объектом FormData. Все данные заносятся через класс. К классу обращаюсь файл ajax.php он же обработчик ajax.js.

```
(ajax.php - обработчик)
     $actions = array(       
        'insert' => array(
          'object' => 'Group',
          'method' => 'insert'
         )
      );


if ( isset($actions[$_POST['action']]) )
{
   $use_array = $actions[$_POST['action']];
   $obj = new $use_array['object'];

if (isset($_POST)){
      unset($_POST['action']);
         $a = array();
         foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value){
              $a[$key]=$value;
         }

       echo $obj->$use_array['method']($a);
   }
```

}

```
function __autoload($class_name)
{
    $filename = './classes/'. strtolower($class_name) . '.class.php';
    if ( file_exists($filename) )
    {
         include_once $filename;
     }
}
```

Кусок кода класса метода обработчика метода: 'method'=>'insert'

```
 public function insert_header(){

// если в массиве $_POST есть ключ name и его значение не равно пустоте, то
      if ((isset($_POST['name'])) && (!empty($_POST["name"]))) {
        // присвоить $result['name'] значение $_POST['name']
        $result['name'] = $_POST['name'];
      } else {
        // иначе, $result['name'] присвоить указанную строку
        $result['name'] = 'Вы не ввели поле name!';
      }
      // если в массиве $_POST есть ключ message и его значение не равно 
      пустоте, то  
      if ((isset($_POST['message']))&& (!empty($_POST["message"]))) {
        // присвоить $result['message'] значение $_POST['message']
        $result['message'] = $_POST['message'];
      } else {
        // иначе, $result['message'] присвоить указанную строку
        $result['message'] = 'Вы не ввели поле message!';
      }
// преобразовать массив $result в json, а затем вывести его с помощью          echo
      echo json_encode($result);
```

Форма которую обрабатывает скрипт:

```
<form id="message">
  <div class="form-group">
     <label for="name">Имя:</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
       <label for="name">Сообщение:</label>
       <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="message"></textarea>
  </div>
   <button id="send-message" class="btn btn-primary">Отправить 
   сообщение</button>
 </form>
```

Теперь код самого ajax.js

```
  $('#message').submit(function(e) {

     var formData = new FormData($('#message')[0]);

     $.ajax({
          url: 'ajax.php',
          data: 'action=insert&'+formData,
          processData: false,
          contentType: false,
          cache:false,
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'JSON',
          success: function(data) {
               var output = '<ul>';
               $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                   output += '<li><b>' + key + "</b>: " + value + '</li>';
               });
               output += '</ul>';
               $('#result').html(output);
          }     
    });
   // отменяем отправку формы стандартным способом
   e.preventDefault();
  });
```

Проблема в том, что не могу передать данные из формы по ссылке из data: - data: 'action=insert&'+formData. Если убрать: " data: 'action=insert&'" и код из обработчика перекинуть в файл ajax.php минуя класс Group, то работает. Так нет. Мне это очень важно, чтобы работало именно через FormData() и через класс Group, т.к. буду передавать файл совместно с другими данными из формы (поле фалй пока не создал, хочу получить чисто данные через метод FormData). Если использую просто сериализацию serialize() и "action=insert&" данные получает метод класса, всё успешно работает.

Пробовал так: formData('action','insert'); не работает. Что посоветуете?

Comment: `var formData = $(this).serialize();`

Comment: .serialize(); не принимает файлы! Именно надо new FormData(); И именно через этот кусок кода: data: 'action=insert&'+formData. Если убрать " 'action=insert&'+" и миновать обработчик в классе, то пашет, а это не то...

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="message">
  <input type="hidden" id="action" name="action" />
  ...

$('#message').submit(function(e) {
  $(this).find("#action").val("insert");
  var formData = new FormData(this);

  $.ajax({
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data: formData,
   ...
```

Comment: Не работает с hidden. По нажатии на кнопку вообще ничего не происходит, консоль молчит. Именно по этой ссылке  " 'action=insert&'+" происходит передача данных в класс Group и в метод "insert". С Сериализацией таким образом работает, а вот new FormData проблема. Всю голову сломал.

Answer (score 0):

`FormData` передается со своим типом, а не `json` или `text` или еще каким.

Таким образом как минимум лишнее указание

```
dataType: 'JSON'
```

Во-вторых, передавать надо сам объект `formData`. В данном же случае

```
'action=insert&'+formData,
```

Идет приведение объекта к строке и в итоге передается `'action=insert[object FormData]'`,

Вместо этого нужно указать непосредственно сам объект:

```
data: formData,
```

Если дополнительно к указанным полям нужно добавить поле `action`, то можно добавить это непосредственно в объект

```
formData.append('action', 'insert')
```

Либо добавить одноименный элемент в форму с указанным значением

```
<form id="message">
  <input type="hidden" id="action" name="action" value="insert" />
```